# Scala found List and SeqProjection, when required Seq and Set

Tags: scala, scala-2.7

Sitting with the following error:

```
TestCaseGenerator.scala:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(State, Seq.Projection[State])]
 required: Seq[(State, Set[State])]
    new LTS(Map(rndTrans: _*), Map(rndLabeling: _*))
                ^
one error found
```

Can't figure out what to do about it.

The `rndTrans` is initialized as follows:

```
val rndTrans = for (s <- (0 to nStates).toList)
                   yield (new State(s) -> (for (s2 <- 0 to nStates
                       if prob(trans_probability))
                           yield new State(s2)))
```

**Update: I happen to be using version 2.7.**

Comment: Please mention that you’re using 2.7… (We should have a tag for that one instead of the scala-2.8 tag nowadays.)

Comment: Sorry about that... I didn't realize that the two versions are so different.

Comment: Concerning collections they are. You maybe should install sbt to get scala 2.8 running easily.

Comment: I've tried installing sbt and failed :-( When I run `sbt` I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject`. You have a suggestion on what I should try, or should I post a separate question?

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I don’t have any quick help for that. Better you ask a new question.

Comment: @Debilski You are absolutely right. As it happens, some of us can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `toSet` method (or `toMap`) is not available (because one is running an older version of scala or because the conversion is just not implemented), one can often apply one of the following schemes.

```
val collection: Seq[SomeType] = ...

Set( collection: _* )
```

or

```
Set() ++ collection
```

The first version uses the `:_*` to convert the collection to a sequence argument and then calls a constructor method of the new collection type. The second method created an empty collection of the new type and then adds (`++`) the old collection to it.

Comment: Thanks! (I'll upvote tomorrow, I've run out of upvotes today )-:

Answer (score 2):

Generally a `Seq` is not a `Set`. Try converting the value sequence to a set.

```
val rndTrans = for (s <- (0 to nStates).toList)
                   yield (new State(s) -> (for (s2 <- 0 to nStates
                       if prob(trans_probability))
                           yield new State(s2)).toSet)
```

Comment: I get `error: value toSet is not a member of Seq.Projection[State]`